# Pass Formik functions and values into jest mocked input

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library, formik

I have a Formik form component that I am trying to test...the troublesome field here is a date component using a third party library called react-datepicker.

Here is how I am doing it in the component I am testing:

```
<InputContainer
        required
        label="Arrival Date and Time"
        name="arrival_date_time"
        id="date_from"
        errors={touched.arrival_date_time && errors.arrival_date_time
            ? errors.arrival_date_time
            : undefined
        }
    >
        <DatePicker
            selected={values.arrival_date_time ? parseISO(values.arrival_date_time) : ""}
            onChange={(value) => setFieldValue("arrival_date_time", moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm'))}
            showTimeInput
            timeInputLabel="Time: "
            dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
            customInput={<Input />}
        />
    </InputContainer>
```

The `InputContainer` is basically only there to handle showing the errors and I am setting the value with the `setFieldValue` from Formik and also using `values` from Formik.

The `DatePicker` component itself doesn't play nice with the tests but thats fine...I don't need to test that specifically so what I want to do is replace it with a normal input field.

In my test file this is how I am mocking it:

```
jest.mock('./InputContainer', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: (props) => <MockDatePickerInput {...props} {...props.children} />
}));
```

Where `MockeDatePickerInput` is:

```
const MockDatePickerInput = ({values, handleChange, touched, errors}) => {
    return (
        <InputField
            name="arrival_date_time"
            id="arrival_date_time"
            type="text"
            value={values.arrival_date_time}
            onChange={handleChange}
            errors={touched.arrival_date_time && errors.arrival_date_time
                ? errors.arrival_date_time
                : undefined
            }
        >
            Arrival Date and Time
        </InputField>
    )
}
```

The problem I am having is that I can't seem to pass through the `handleChange` `values` `touched` and `errors` that it needs, or would be getting from within the component where they are in scope and I am not really sure how to do this in a test environment.

I get the following error when trying to run the test:

[image: jest values error]

The thing is, while I realise that in one instance I am using `setFieldValue` and in the mock I am using `handleChange` and that may cause my next problem, this is erroring out on `values` which is used in both scenarios...

Is what I am trying to do here even possible?